# Writing numpy array as VTK file

Tags: python, vtk

I have a 2D numpy array that I wish to export and write as a VTK file. I have tried the vtk package as well as PyEVTK package but am running into issues with both.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
from vtk.util import numpy_support
numpy_to_vtk(num_array, deep=0, array_type=None)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this but am unsure from here how to export the VTK array into an actual VTK file.

Comment: Have you read this? https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Writing_VTK_files_using_python

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you asking for?
It is easy to use but you have to know the connectivity of yourElements

```
import meshio 

yourNodes = np.array([...])
yourElements = np.array([...])
cells = [("triangle", yourElements )]
mesh = meshio.Mesh(yourNodes , cells )
mesh.write("foo.vtk")
```

yourElements start at 0 and not at 1!